# unity xml configuration generic interfaces

Tags: .net, configuration, unity-container

I'm using Unity for constructor injection. Constructor injection via the runtime API succeeds with the following code:

```
{
using ContractImplementations;
using Contracts;
using DataAccess;
using DataModel.Entities;
using DataModel.Interfaces;

using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;

using Unity.Wcf;

/// <summary>
/// The wcf service factory.
/// </summary>
public class WcfServiceFactory : UnityServiceHostFactory
{
    #region Methods
    /// <summary>
    /// Configure container.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="container">
    /// The container.
    /// </param>
    protected override void ConfigureContainer(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container
           .RegisterType<IGaugeModelbaseService, GaugeModelbaseService>()
           .RegisterType<IContractMapper, ContractMapper>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager())
           .RegisterType<IGenericRepository<GaugeModel>, GenericSqlRepository<GaugeModel>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

Because of integration with AppFabric and  EntLib however I have to configure the container in XML config. Problem: The unity documentation is not clear on the subject of registering generic types. According to the documentation, I have to do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<namespace name="Design.ModelbaseSvc" />
<assembly name="Design.ModelbaseSvc" />
<namespace name="Design.ContractImplementations" />
<assembly name="Design.ContractImplementations" />
<namespace name="Design.DataModel" />
<assembly name="Design.DataModel" />
<namespace name="Design.DataAccess" />
<assembly name="Design.DataAcces" />


<container>
  <register type="IGaugeModelbaseService" mapTo="GaugeModelbaseService">
    <interceptor type="InterfaceInterceptor" />
  </register>
  <register type="IContractMapper" mapTo="ContractMapper">
    <lifetime type="hierarchical" />
  </register>
  <register type="IGenericRepository'1[Design.DataModel.Entities.GaugeModel, Design.DataModel]" mapTo="GenericSqlRepository'1[Design.DataModel.Entities.GaugeModel, Design.DataModel]">       
    <lifetime type="hierarchical" />
  </register>
</container>
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, but this doesn't work:
- the XML-editor gives errors on using parenthesis "[]"
- Browsing the svc-file give the folowing error:

> The type name or alias IGenericRepository'1[Design.DataModel.Entities.GaugeModel, Design.DataModel] could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name.

I tried several other and it finally leads to brain death. Please help.

Thanks

Frans Verhoeven

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this in XML and with Unity?

Comment: XML is very verbose, error prone, and hard to maintian. You can use `RegisterType` to map an open generic type, but there is no easy way to do batch registration of generic types in Unity.

Answer (score 1):

For each type [you must specify the assembly and the full namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660933%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx), or you can use [aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660914%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx#config_aliases).

With generic types, if you don't use aliases you have to use double square brackets:

```
<register 
      type="MyNameSpace.IGenericRepository'1[[Design.DataModel.Entities.GaugeModel, Design.DataModel]], MyAssembly"       
     mapTo="MyNameSpace.GenericSqlRepository'1[[Design.DataModel.Entities.GaugeModel, Design.DataModel]], MyAssembly">       
    <lifetime type="hierarchical" />
</register>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case it doesn't however solve the problem. I still get the same error browsing the svc-file. My xml-editor (Visual Studio) as before also gives the following error on the square brackets "Unexpected text".